# How to fix the perpetual loader in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-18

in StrictMode mode, the component is not rendered repeatedly when the state changes

```
const isShowLoader = useStoreSelector((state) => state.global.loadingSlice.isLoading)

const isLoading = useMemo(() => isShowLoader, [isShowLoader])


...

useEffect(() => {

  ...
  
  dispatch(setLoading(false))
   
}, [currentLocation.name, isLoading])


{isLoading
  && (
    <PageLoader />
  )}
```